# Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '32012' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, primary-key

I've just seen this error in one of our Rails apps that uses MySQL. We had this row in the database:

```
mysql> select * from user_notes where id='32012';
+-------+---------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id    | user_id | admin_user | comment            | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-------+---------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 32012 | 1517776 | foo        | ID: DIl4Zy7mgo9fQ0 | 2018-07-26 13:30:33 | 2018-07-26 13:30:33 |
+-------+---------+------------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Then, at, we got this error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '32012' for key 'PRIMARY':
INSERT INTO `user_notes` (`admin_user`, `comment`, `user_id`, `created_at`,
    `updated_at`) VALUES
('foo', 'ID: DIlKKFX2jLxh3p', 1517788, '2018-07-26 13:46:51', '2018-07-26 13:46:51')
```

So, the takeaway is that a new record was attempted to be inserted in the database and for some weird reason, the same primary key as for the record inserted ~16mins before was being used.

The record with is `32013` (the next one) was inserted at `2018-07-26 13:54:24`, so that is fine.

I would assume the internal primary key incrementor didn't do its job after inserting record `32012`, but how would that be possible? Any tips appreciated! It is important to mention that this was an isolated event.

FYI: `user_notes` looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_notes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_user_notes_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `index_user_notes_on_admin_user` (`admin_user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=33082 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: As far as I know, that insert statement could not have generated the error message you are seeing.  Is there any chance that someone there are already two records with `32012` as the `id` value?  That would be my first guess; the insert just caused MySQL to hiccup again.

Comment: No, it's just one with `32012` as the `id`. It is the primary key on the table, so we couldn't have just added a duplicate there. The insert statement is also generated by the same script that populated the entire table, so it can't be something wrong there.

Comment: Then I'm stumped.  If `id` is an auto increment column, and there is only one record in the table, then how did the value `32012` get there in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, I meant one record with that `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems we have been running some database-related upgrades during this time, and the error more than sure occurred because of this. We haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the error.